# GaussianBlur for 3D images in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 3D image that i want to blur thanks to a Gaussian filter. I did the same things before in 2D using :

```
K=torchvision.transforms.GaussianBlur((ksize,ksize),sigma)
imgblur=K(img)
```

However, this function doesn't seem to work for 3d images of shape (64,64,64) for example. Do you know how can i do ?